# How can I compare tho properties using grails Searchable Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, searchable-plugin

Given the following domain class:

```
class Test {
    String name
    Integer val1, val2
}
```

I'm currently searching this class with the following criteria:

```
Test.createCriteria().list(params) {
    params.key.split(' ').each {
        ilike('name', "%${it}%")
    }
    gtProperty('val1', 'val2')
}
```

I'm trying to use [Grails Searchable Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/searchable)  to improve my search results. More specifically its [Query Builder](https://grails.org/wiki/Searchable%20Plugin%20-%20Searching%20-%20Query%20Builder). The only problem is that I can't find a way to filter results where `val1 > val2`. As shown bellow:

```
Test.search(params) {
    must(queryString(params.key))
    must(
        // Something to require that val1 > val2
    )
}
```

I could filter it after searching but it would mess pagination.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this?

```
def result = Test.where {
    it.name = name
    it.val1 > val2
}
```

edit:
In the documentation it shows this as an example

```
search {                    // <-- create an implicit boolean query
    lt("pages", 50)         // <-- uses CompassQueryBuilder#lt, and adds a boolean "should" clause
    term("type", "poetry")  // <-- uses CompassQueryBuilder#term, and adds a boolean "should" clause
}
```

So would something like this work for you? Not sure on the syntax, never used this before.

```
search {                      
    term("name", foo) 
    gt("val1", val2)
}
```

Comment: Well, I'd like to improve my search results with the Compass Engine provided by the Searchable Plugin. This way I can sort results according with it's similarity with the query string, suggest a new query if too few results are found and so on

Comment: Edited my question to clarify it a bit more

Comment: @ylima I added more to the answer

Comment: Yeah. I need something like that. But I need to compare two properties instead of a property and a constant